# Having trobule with displaying the calendars correct date

Tags: java, android

So my widget pulls up correctly but it wont display the correct selection once the user has made a choice. Here is my code.

```
SimpleDateFormat dayFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM FF, yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

This is run at the beginning of my code and when the widget get pulled up it displays the correct date. It might have something to do with why I have my original problem but I am at a lost and don't know how to fix this.

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        int w = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        Date z = cal.getTime();
        description.setText(gDate.date(w, year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth) + 
                "\n" + dayFormatter.format(z));
```

And here is the output.

Monday, July 14, 2011

Monday, July 02, 2011

```
gDate.date(w, year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth)
```

This code above is a class I created to do this with a string before I learned about SimpleDateFormat. This is the string that is on top and displays the right date. Also I don't understand why the second date starts where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your pattern from `"EEEE, MMMM FF, yyyy"` to `"EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"`

FF is day of week in month, dd is day in month. See the javadoc for [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Thank you sir. I love work that is put into the most simplest of mistakes thinking it is something big.